# Dudley's Theorem for sub-gaussian process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

The text I am using is Mathematical foundation of infinite dimensional statistical model. Here is the statement of Dudley's Theorem. [image]

The statement says the (2.43) holds for sub-Gaussian, but the proof only shows (2.44) holds for sub-gaussian process while (2.43) holds for Gaussian process. The proof cannot not be generalized as it requires linear combination of projections to be gaussian, in order to deduce some concentration inequalities of max.

I am wondering if it is possible to show if (2.43) holds for Gaussian process, then it holds for sub-gaussian process, as Gaussian process has maximum variance. But after some attempts I feel this method does not work.

Does anyone have any comments or hints? Thanks in advance.